# Is my Skolem normal form of $(\forall x \exists y\exists zT(x,y)\land S(y,z))\land(\lnot\forall yP(y))$ correct?

Tags: predicate-logic

Is my skolem normal form of $(\forall x \exists y \exists z T(x,y)\land S(y,z))\land (\lnot \forall yP(y))$ correct?

$$
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      ( \forall x \exists y \exists z \; T(x,y) \land S(y,z) )
      \land (\neg \forall y \; P(y))
    & \leftarrow\text{Given formula}
    \\
    \hline
      ( \forall x \exists y \exists z \; T(x,y) \land S(y,z))
      \land (\neg \forall y \; P(y))
    & \text{Rename variables and}
    \\
      {}
    & \text{change quantors}
    \\
    \hline
      ( \forall x \exists y \exists z \; (T(x,y) \land S(y,z)) )
      \land (\exists v \; \neg P(v))
    & \text{Remove $()$ and move}
    \\
      {}
    & \text{$\exists v$ to the left side}
    \\
    \hline
      \forall x \exists y \exists z \exists u
      \; T(x,y) \land S(y,z) \land \neg P(u)
    & \text{It is in PNF. Do:}
    \\
      {}
    & \exists y = i(x); 
      \exists z = k(x);
    \\
      {}
    & \exists u = h(x)
    \\
    \hline
      \forall x \; T(x, i(x)) \land Q(f(x), k(x)) \land \neg P(h(x))
    & \text{It is in SNF.}
    \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$
(Original picture of the calculation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxFl.png).)

Comment: Thanks for your corrections @Bernard - did you also check the calculations?

Comment: It's beyond my capabilities, unfortunately.